# In SAS University Edition when using the command Proc Corresp with BINARY option I get the answer as "output data larger than 3MB

Tags: sas, binary

My dataset has 45,000 observations including a some missing values.I need inertia information and finally see graphically the variable directions displayed as four quadrants with variables falling in different quadrants depending on the variables.Finally I want to run cluster analysis with the coordinates found.

Code:

```
{
     proc corresp data=work.temp observed short binary;

     title2 'Binary Coding';
     ods select binary;
     var var1-var20;run;
}
```

Comment: Show your log please.

Comment: Thankyou. The command when run says results cannot be displayed due to lack of space. I want a binary table to run multiple correspondence analysis(MCA) and further cluster analysis using the dimension coordinates from MCA.